# How to check if a file doesn't exist in github?

Tags: github-actions

So far the only thing I know what to do with a conditional is check if a variable is a certain value or if it starts with a certain string. What I don't know how to do is check if a file exists or not.

Ideally I would like to do something like this inside my yaml file:

```yaml
- name: Creating file
  if: "!test-path 'cat\\cat.txt'"
  echo "Cat doesnt exist creating now"
```

If I can't figure out a solution for this I will have to do it inside my gradle files and use groovy and then call it with gradlew in my yaml. Another alternative I found was using marketplace as mentioned in: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/check-file-existence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, [expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions) doesn't support something like this out of the box.

So, you have to resort to checking file existence from the shell that you're using in your GHA workflow e.g. `pwsh`, `sh`, `bash`, etc.

See [`jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].shell`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsshell) for more details.

According to the default/configured `shell`, you'll be using its respective commands/facilities to check the file existence under [`jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].run`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun).

For example, with [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html), you would do something like this:

```yaml
- name: Check file existence
  env:
    FILE: file.txt
  shell: bash
  run: |
    if [[ -f $FILE ]]; then
      echo "$FILE exists!"
    else
      echo "$FILE does not exist!"
    fi
```

As for using something in [`jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].if`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsif) directly, you need to have something to work with e.g. via an [environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable) or [output parameter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter).